# Finding Row in dataframe and changing value in cell - Rstudio

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a problem with script in R. I've got a dataframe (CSV) with few hundred rows in each file. I want to compare to files (newer with older one). In the older one there are certain values like Country, Customer_ID, Category and the Representative_ID. Each Customer has a client. And sometimes client changes. And the changes are in each file. So the oldest file(dataframe) is basic database, in following file, there are only changes. So lets say:

```
PL|Pharmacy|WPLF1111123233|F111
```

where WPLF1111123233 is the CustomerID and F112 is the RepresentativeID

in the next data frame there is

```
PL|Pharmacy|WPLF1111123233|F333
```

which is the same thing like above, but the same Representative has changed from F111 to F333

so I tried to use formula like this. To check the ID of client in the first data frame and in the second one, and if in the second one, the ClientID is present it means that Representative has been changed so in the first file i should change it too.

```
dataset$RepID <- ifelse ((dataset$CustomerID %in% dataset2$CustomerID), dataset2$RepID, dataset$RepID)
```

where dataset is just the first dataframe, and the dataset2 is the dataframe with changes. "RepID" is the column with representative ID. I used Ifelse because normal If doesn't work for vectors. The thing is false because it doesn't have any order and I don't quite know how to omit that. I've been looking for an answer but couldn't find any. Thank you for your help.

In general I have like 350 files, but to do this it's gonna be one simple loop so that is not the problem.

EDIT: 
OLD DATA TO CHECK

```
D|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF00003224|25|F123|1
D|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02818905|26|F120|1
I|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02615545|20|F110|1
I|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02615553|36|F112|1
I|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02615557|01|F106|1
I|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02615561|36|F112|1
I|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02615564|31|F101|1
I|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF00007731|34|F132|1
```

CHANGES:

```
D|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF07253186|17|Grandpa|1
D|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF00003224|25|Pontiac|1
D|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02818905|26|Catalina|1
I|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02615545|20|Chicago|1
I|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02615557|01|Foxtrot|1
I|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02615553|36|Tango|1
I|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02615561|36|Hollywood|1
I|PL|Terytorium_nowe|WPLF02615564|31|Zulu|1
```

So the list from the DataToCheck should be updated -> names should be changed from `F(numbers)` to `Nato Alphabet` and row with ID `WPLF00007731` and ID `F132` from DataToCheck should not be touched or changed and row from Changes with `Grandpa` should be added to the first DataToCheck

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide sample data of your dataframes to try it out.

Comment: @msr_003 edited with data

Comment: Would be helpful if the data was reproducible (using dput or similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with basic looping way. (Change column names according to your dataframe.)

```
OLD_DATA_TO_CHECK 

   Col1  Country Category        Customer_Id   Col5 Col6   Col7
1 D     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF00003224    25 F123      1
2 D     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02818905    26 F120      1
3 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615545    20 F110      1
4 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615553    36 F112      1
5 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615557     1 F106      1
6 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615561    36 F112      1
7 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615564    31 F101      1
8 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF00007731    34 F132      1 


CHANGES

    Col1  Country Category        Customer_Id   Col5 Col6       Col7
1 D     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF07253186    17 Grandpa       1
2 D     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF00003224    25 Pontiac       1
3 D     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02818905    26 Catalina      1
4 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615545    20 Chicago       1
5 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615557     1 Foxtrot       1
6 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615553    36 Tango         1
7 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615561    36 Hollywood     1
8 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615564    31 Zulu          1
```

Here I'm assuming `OLD_DATA_TO_CHECK` is your old data which is to be modified with respect to the requirements.

```
for(i in 1:length(OLD_DATA_TO_CHECK$Customer_Id)){
  for(j in 1:length(CHANGES$Customer_Id)){
    if(OLD_DATA_TO_CHECK$Customer_Id[i] != 'WPLF00007731' & OLD_DATA_TO_CHECK$Col6[i] != "F132"){  # Checking for the row which shold not modify
      if(OLD_DATA_TO_CHECK$Customer_Id[i] == CHANGES$Customer_Id[j]){
        OLD_DATA_TO_CHECK$Col6[i] <- CHANGES$Col6[j]
        if(CHANGES$Col6[i] == 'Grandpa'){
         OLD_DATA_TO_CHECK <- rbind(CHANGES[i,], OLD_DATA_TO_CHECK) # binding the identified row from CHANGES to top row of OLD_DATA_TO_CHECK 
       } 
    }
  }
  }
}

OLD_DATA_TO_CHECK #after modifications

  Col1  Country Category        Customer_Id   Col5 Col6       Col7
1 D     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF07253186    17 Grandpa       1
2 D     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF00003224    25 Pontiac       1
3 D     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02818905    26 Catalina      1
4 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615545    20 Chicago       1
5 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615553    36 Tango         1
6 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615557     1 Foxtrot       1
7 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615561    36 Hollywood     1
8 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF02615564    31 Zulu          1
9 I     PL      Terytorium_nowe WPLF00007731    34 F132          1
```

Comment: thank you for answer! Thank helped. Not exactly what I meant but with the inspiration I've solved the problem. Earlier I've just thought that I can do this using only vectors, but the problem was the order of rows in data. Now everything works perfectly